# Cannot mount hfs partition on read/write

Tags: fstab, automount, hfs+

In ubuntu 15.10 I am trying to mount a hfs (max osx) partition on start up. In **/etc/fstab** I have added this line (notice the **rw** option):

```
/dev/sda2 /home/mac/mac-mount hfsplus rw,defaults 0 0
```

After a reboot the drive is mounted but I cannot create new content on the drive:

```
:~/mac-mount/Users/mac-mini/Documents$ touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘test.txt’: Read-only file system
```

Running mount gives me the below for that particular partition:

```
/dev/sda2 on /home/mac/mac-mount type hfsplus (ro,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8)
```

notice it says **ro**. Why is the hfs partition not mounted in **rw** given the **/etc/fstab** file above?

I have also tried to change the permissions for the mount point with:

```
~$ sudo chmod o+w mac-mount/
[sudo] password for mac:
chmod: changing permissions of ‘mac-mount/’: Read-only file system
```

But it gives the above error.

**UPDATE:** Based on the below answer I now have it working with write permissions after disabling Journaling. But for some reason it only works on some folders (I managed to create a test file in the **Documents** folder). As and example I cannot even *cd* to the **Downloads** folder on the hfs partition:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1  501 dialout    17 Dec 29 14:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root      80     6 Oct  6 16:54 ..
drwx------ 1  501 dialout     3 Aug 10  2014 Applications
-rw-r--r-- 1  501 dialout    56 Dec 29 14:12 .bash_history
drwxr-xr-x 1  501 dialout     5 Dec 29 14:12 .bash_sessions
-r-------- 1  501 dialout     7 Feb 14  2015 .CFUserTextEncoding
drwx------ 1  501 dialout     4 Oct 13 18:30 Desktop
drwx---rwx 1  501 dialout    12 Dec 29 14:15 Documents
drwx------ 1  501 dialout     6 Dec 29 14:11 Downloads
-rw-r--r-- 1  501 dialout 14340 Dec 29 14:10 .DS_Store
drwx------ 1  501 dialout    52 Oct  6 17:13 Library
drwx------ 1  501 dialout     3 Aug 10  2014 Movies
drwx------ 1  501 dialout     5 Sep 13  2014 Music
drwxr-xr-x 1  501 dialout     3 Oct 28 11:34 .oracle_jre_usage
drwx------ 1  501 dialout     8 Apr 17  2015 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 1  501 dialout     5 Aug 10  2014 Public
drwx------ 1  501 dialout     6 Dec 27 01:49 .Trash
:~/mac-mount/Users/mac-mini$ cd Downloads/
-bash: cd: Downloads/: Permission denied
:~/mac-mount/Users/mac-mini$ cd Documents/
:~/mac-mount/Users/mac-mini/Documents$
```

So why can I cd to **Documents** but not **Downloads** folder? I have not modified any permissions while using my mac-mini directly.

Comment: The permission issue would be handled better in a [new question](/questions/ask). You can either use super-user privileges to override permissions or look into [How to mount HFS+ drive and ignore permissions](/q/100167/175814) for unprivileged access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount this filesystem in Ubuntu with read only access by default. If you need read/write access then you have to disable journaling with OS X before you can continue.

You can identify the volume with:

```
sudo diskutil list
```

and take note of the volume with type "Apple_HFS", usually named "Macintosh HD"

To disabile journaling in OSX type in a terminal:

```
sudo diskutil disableJournal volumeName
```

If you want access in rw mode for a non root user you need to change your Ubuntu User ID (UID) to match your UID under OSX.

Assuming you are logged in as a regular user who has sudo rights. Substitute the username for the Linux user you wish to enable HFS+ write access for and 501 for the relevant OSX UID. You have to modify also the linux UID for the user's home:

```
sudo usermod -u 501 <username>
sudo chown -R 501:<username> /home/<username>
```

If there are in your system others files that belongs to the user you can change alla UIDs in one command. Take note of your UID (with `id` command), then:

```
find / -uid <useractualUID> -exec chown 501:<username> {} +
```

You may also want to fix your login screen, by default Ubuntu doesn't list users with a UID < 1000. Open a Terminal and run

`sudo nano /etc/login.defs`

Then search for UID_MIN. Change that value from 1000 to 501, when you reboot your user will be listed on the login screen.

Comment: That got me closer to a solution. But for some reason I cannot access some folders. Could that be related to the user UI? Not really sure where I should lookup/set that based on your answer.

Comment: I improved my answer, I hope this can help you

Comment: I tried what you suggest above. I had to login as another user that then one I want to change the ID for since I kept getting: usermod: user mac is currently used by process 2246. After killing all the processes and logging in as the other other user and executing the usermod command it just hangs. So it seems that I cannot change the UID based on the above recipe.

Comment: did you try the link suggested by David Foerster ? At least can you access the files with root user?